# Opening an Emacs file to a specific word in the file

Tags: search, find-file

In Vim it is trivial to open a file from the command line to a specific word in the document. For e.g. to open the file "Contacts.txt" to "Bob" one would type:

vim Contacts.txt +/Bob

In Emacs it seems that one can only to this with a line number and or column but not a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ emacs Contacts.txt --eval '(search-forward "Bob")'
```

Comment: Was just posting a similar answer :) I'd just use `'(search-forward "Bob" nil t)'` to avoid an error if Bob isn't there.

Comment: Also to place point on match beginning: `emacs Contacts.txt --eval '(when (search-forward "Bob" nil t)(goto-char (match-beginning 0)))'`

Comment: By the way, you can also define a function in your init file and use it from command line, e.g., `emacs Contacts.txt --eval '(+/ "Bob")'`. Editing Lisp in command line is painful.